# If no input is given to xargs, don't let xargs run the utility

Tags: pipe, xargs, newlines

I have this command:

```
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs docker volume rm
```

I get this:

> ```
> "docker volume rm" requires at least 1 argument.
> See 'docker volume rm --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker volume rm [OPTIONS] VOLUME [VOLUME...]
> ```

I assume it's because there was no input to `xargs` (because there were no matching volumes returned by the `docker` command). How can I tell `xargs` to do *nothing* when it receives no input?

Comment: Similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440312/preventing-posix-xargs-from-attempting-to-run-an-empty-command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for the `-r` option.  This is a non-standard option which  may be implemented on your system (check your `xargs` manual).

From the GNU `xargs` manual:

> `-r`, `--no-run-if-empty`
>
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the  command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.

From the manual on an OpenBSD system:

> `-r`
>
> Do not run the command if there are no arguments.  Normally the
> command is executed at least once even if there are no arguments.

On FreeBSD and macOS, this is the default behavior. FreeBSD has the `-r` option for compatibility with GNU `xargs`, while macOS does not.

`xargs` on AIX and Solaris does not have a `-r` option, and it is unknown what the default behavior is on AIX (I don't have access to an AIX system). Solaris will run the utility at least once by default.

---

One portable work-around on systems with no `-r` flag for `xargs` (and where running the utility at east once is the default behavior, as on Solaris) is to use

```
something | xargs sh -c '[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && utility "$@"' sh
```

(or something like it; note that the trailing `sh` is required) where `utility` is the utility that you'd like to run with `xargs`, and where `something` produces some arguments.

The short shell script `[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && utility "$@"` tests whether it was given any arguments, and if so, it runs the utility with those arguments.

Comment: "note that the trailing `sh` is required" You could pass the utility as an argument instead: `something | xargs sh -c '[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && exec "$0" "$@"' utility`. Idea taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34440764/10095231 - `xargs sh -c '[ $# -gt 0 ] && exec "$0" "$@"' kill`.

Comment: @kelvin `$0` is used by the shell in diagnostic/error messages. To have the shell output error messages with the name of some other utility other than itself would make any debugging highly confusing. I would rather pass it in `$1` and shift it off: `-exec sh -c 'util=$1;shift; [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && "$util" "$@" sh "some_utility"`

Comment: That makes sense. Alternatively, I considered passing `$0` as the first argument (i.e.: for when using xargs from inside a script) instead of the utility, as that would make the error message prefix the same as in the other error messages from the script. But would make error messages confusing for e.g.: shell syntax errors, as it would always print `myscript: line 1: ` (with `line 1` coming from `sh -c` of course), so nevermind.