# How to execute the next command in pipe only if previous have at least one result?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

So, I have the following command

```
$(docker container ls -a -q) | docker container stop
```

to stop all my docker containers, which works great! Except when I've just wiped clean all of them:

```
"docker container stop" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker container stop --help'.

Usage:  docker container stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Stop one or more running containers
```

Is there any way I can prevent this error message from showing up using a single line command?

Note: my original command was actually `docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q)`, which gives the same error message, but I tought it would be easier to describe my problem using pipe/chain one command to the other. Answers for both commands are OK, but I'll prefer to use `docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q)`

Comment: I'm pretty certain `$(docker container ls -a -q) | docker container stop` doesn't work great at all. At the very least if you wanted to use a pipe that should be `docker container ls -a -q | xargs docker container stop`

Comment: And for xargs there's https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521595/70524

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the N-ary stop operation of Docker is silly with regard to zero containers, what you can do is treat `docker stop container` as as a unary operation which requires exactly one argument, and do your own distribution of a list of terms over that unary operation. Of course, such a way that your logic handles the empty sequence of terms:

```
for x in $(docker container ls -a -q); do docker container stop $x; done
```

If `$(docker ...)` produces nothing, the loop doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence shell output using redirects, see this post for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292847/how-to-silence-output-in-a-bash-script

I might use something more like this to handle the response so I still get output.

```bsh
docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q) >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Nothing to stop."
```